# Show answers in review tool, at least for some questions

Tags: feature-request, review

The "Review Close Votes" part of the review tool shows questions and the number of existing answers, but it doesn't show the actual answers.

I understand that there are good reasons for this – first and foremost (I guess), that we are to vote on the questions, not the combination of questions and answers, which is something that I am sure has an impact on voting behaviour.

Nevertherless, there is one type of question where it would be really useful to get the answers displayed right below the question: Questions that were voted to be closed as too-localized.

The **reason** why I think it would be useful is this: Candidates for "too localized" tend to include a lot of code. It can take minutes to figure out, just by reading that code, whether the question addresses a problem of general interest or is really too localized. But the answers (often self-given) can reveal this very quickly. ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15145346/compiler-error-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64). This isn't the best possible example, because the title of the question is also a powerful indicator of this being too localized. Nevertheless, it demonstrates how the answer makes this clear instantly.)

I encounter this type of situation frequently in the context of

- questions about problems that are really the result of typos in the code
- questions about problems that result from other kinds of "silly" mistakes that no future user will benefit from

Is there any chance that answer-display could be provided, at least for "too localized" candidates?

Comment: Just a "Show answers" button would be helpful.

Comment: Also, you get to see answers to potential duplicates, and then I notice that the original question has an accepted answer and wonder whether there is still any utility in marking it as a duplicate...